# Django: How to query objects immediately after they have been saved from a separate view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Suppose I want to query and display **all the images that the user *just* uploaded through a form on the previous page** (multiple images are uploaded at once, each is made into a separate object in the db).

**What's the best way to do this?**

Since the view for uploading the images is different from the view for displaying the images, how does the second view know which images were part of that upload? I thought about creating and saving the image objects in the first view, gathering the `pk`s, and passing them to the second view, but I understand that it is bad practice. So how should I make sure the second view knows which primary keys to query for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs) are for - you'd store the pk's into the session, and then read them back out on the next page.

Comment: This looks like the solution I might be looking for. Can you think of any problems if the user uses the upload page more than once in any given session? Wouldn't it return **all** the pks uploaded thus far in that session?

Comment: That's up to you! On the next page, you could clear out those values from the session when you retrieve them, or you could append to them - it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

What other fields are there in the model db?
You could add an upload_id, which is set automatically after uploading, send it to the next view, and query for that in the db.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but how would I "send it to the next view"?

Comment: What are the images for? Album or some kind of product?
Would be easier if you posted your view function.

However, I think girasquid's solution might be the best one

Comment: another thing: the page that displays the images - is it only a "preview"? Or has the images actually been saved to the db at that point

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The images have already been resized by PIL and saved. It's not a preview, but rather a page to add a title and a caption to each image object. (To answer your previous comment the images are uploaded to a user's photo library on a site, but I don't think that affects this)